# regex to find a string in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string  like this :

```
<input name="my_name" id="my_id" value="my_value" class="my_class" />
```

I would like to find what is inside the "id", i.e. 'my_id'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `document.form_name.my_name.id` should get you what you want.

Comment: What is the language that you are writing the program to extract data?

Comment: it is in html/javascript, but in this particular issue, i have just a string. so retrieving it through the dom is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not load a full DOM manipulation library if this is all you need.

If you have a string, you can turn it into a DOM element, and get the `id` property.

```
var my_string = '<input name="my_name" id="my_id" value="my_value" class="my_class" />';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = my_string;

var id = div.firstChild.id;
```

---

Or just use a regular expression...

```
var my_string = '<input name="my_name" id="my_id" value="my_value" class="my_class" />';

var id = /id\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/.exec(my_string);

if (id) id = id[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a simple jquery function like this

```
var currentId = $(".my_class").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use a regex for parsing HTML element attributes, the following JavaScript snippet should do the trick.

```
var regex = /id="([^"]+)"/
var string = '<input name="my_name" id="my_id" value="my_value" class="my_class" />';
var matches = string.match(regex);

var id_val = matches && matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it just using strings and not DOM models, then use.

```
function TextBetween (str,first,second) {
    if (str==null) {
        alert("Unexpected page formatting, please reload.");
        return "";
    }
    var x = str.indexOf(first) + first.length;
    var z = str.substr(x);
    var y = z.indexOf(second);
    return z.substr(z,y);

    }

var inputString = '<input name="my_name" id="my_id" value="my_value" class="my_class" />';
var id = TextBetween(inputString,'id="','"');
```

Otherwise others have pointed out ways to solve it already.